# Proving $ \frac{x^2\sin x}{3\sqrt{x+1}}$ DNE

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Not sure how to prove this; WolframAlpha [tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20x%20approaches%20infinity%20of%20x%5E2sin%28x%29%2F%28sqrt%28x%2B1%29%29) that the result is indeterminate. My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2\sin x}{3\sqrt{x+1}}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2\sin x}{3\sqrt{x+1}}\cdot \frac{1/x^2}{1/x^2}
\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1\cdot \sin x}{3\sqrt{x+1}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}}
\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{3\sqrt{x+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4}}}
\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{3\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^4}}}
\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{3\sqrt{1/x^3+1/x^4}}
\end{align*}
Any hints using introductory calculus principles (no L'Hopital's Rule or further) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin(x)$ oscillates between $+1$ and $-1$, while $x^2/(3 \sqrt{x+1}) > x$ when $x$ is large enough.  So for any $L$ there are arbitrarily large $x$ where your function is far away from $L$, therefore the limit does not exist.  The limit is also not $+\infty$, because there are arbitrarily large $x$ where the value is negative, and not $-\infty$, because there are arbitrarily large $x$ where the value is positive.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes really easy to see this by graphs. To get an approximate graph of $\sin(x)\cdot f(x)$ , we draw $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$. Then we draw a smooth zigzag curve between the two curves to get the approximate graph.

> I am presenting a few of them:
>
> $x\sin(x)$
>
> [image: graph1]
>
> $\frac{x^2}{100}\sin(x)$
>
> [image: graph2]
>
> $\ln(x)\sin(x)$
>
> [image: graph3]

Now, the graph of $f(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{3\sqrt{x+1}}$ tends to infinity at $x\to\infty$ and $-f(x)$ tends to negative infinity as $x\to\infty$

As the graph of $f(x)\sin(x)$ oscillates, so it would not have any well defined limit as $x\to\infty$

[image: graph4]

That is an intuitive answer for you. Cheers :)